# Align Text of BottomNavigationView to bottom or add margin

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Used : `BottomNavigationViewEx`

Want to align Text or add margin of Bottom Navigation Tab. Not able to find method which will push Text of Bottom bit on edge of bottom.

Layout :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.application.ui.view.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/login_orange"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_state"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_state"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Tried :

- Setting Icon Margin but it doesn't push  text.

Need :

- `Align Text to Bottom or atleast add margin from Icon`

[image]

Comment: post xml.......

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae : Please check OP. I don't think so we need to check the layout in this case.

Comment: @VikalpPatel you need to create custom layout for that

Comment: @NileshRathod : Can i attach custom layout for BottomNavigationView?

Comment: @VikalpPatel ping me on hangout i will send u demo project for that hope it will help you